# Inno Setup Disable checkbox if another checkbox is selected

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to disable some checkbox if another one as been selected yet.
How can I do this?

This is my code:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  AddonPage:= CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks,'','Please choose BlueDose preference:');

  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(AddonPage);
  CheckListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  CheckListBox.ParentColor := True;
  CheckListBox.MinItemHeight := WizardForm.TasksList.MinItemHeight;
  CheckListBox.ShowLines := False;
  CheckListBox.WantTabs := True;
  CheckListBox.Parent := AddonPage.Surface;
  CheckListBox.AddGroup('Select Language:', '', 0, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Italian', '', 0, False, True, False, true, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('English', '', 0, False, True, False, true, nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not want checkboxes at all, you want radio buttons:

```pascal
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('Italian', '', 0, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('English', '', 0, False, True, nil);
```

[image]

---

You can also consider using [`CreateInputOptionPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage) instead of generic `CreateCustomPage`. Your code will be much simpler:

```pascal
var
  AddonPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  AddonPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpSelectTasks, '', 'Please choose BlueDose preference:', 'Select language',
      True, False);

  AddonPage.Add('Italian');
  AddonPage.Add('English');
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl , i use `CreateCustomPage` because i have more controls. i have 2 group of `chechbox` and 2 `TNewEdit` and i prefer to use chechbox if it's possible.

Comment: Everything is possible. But would you explain why you want to use checkboxes, if only one option is possible? It's confusing for the user.

Comment: I honestly prefer Chechbox because is graphically more elegant but if there are no alternatives I will use the radio buttons.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to help you with breaking user expectations. Check boxes and radio buttons have a long established use and designs. Do not try to change that.